# Connecting from Mac OS X 10.6 to MS SQLServer

Tags: mac, sql-server

I develop iPhone Apps so my set up is a Mac running Snow Leopard (10.6). However the databases that the App connects to all run SQL Server (2005 or 2008).

I would like a native (free?) solution to allow me to run queries etc.

Virtualization is an option but I'd rather have a native solution, GUI or CLI is fine (both would be preferable).

Comment: Is this more of a Serve fault question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) costs $70, but it is native for MacOS X. There is a full-feature 30 day trial version available so you can determine of it's worth the money.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may like [SQLPro for MSSQL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sql-client-database-management/id828466809?mt=12). (You can also get a trail [at our website](http://macsqlclient.com))

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Syntax highlighting.
- Intellisense.
- Tabbed based interface.
- Support for executing multiple queries at once.
- Quick access to tables, columns and more.
- Stored procedure execution.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452?tab=votes#tab-top) question on Stack Overflow.  The Oracle client with MS plugin looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

- Toad (Mac, Windows) FREE
- Dbeaver (Mac, Windows) FREE
- Sequel Pro (Mac) FREE
- MySQL Workbench (Mac, Windows) FREE

All of these database clients accept local connections with MAMP (Mac, Windows) FREE.

Use the port displayed in the MAMP webpage when the connection is done and the following configs.

Name : localhost
Address : 127.0.0.1
User : root
Password : root
MAMP port

If you need more security than a simple query then pay.